# Pandas retrieve data with a specific order FAST

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get a number of entries at once in a specific order of an ID column values. To make things more complicated, as input I have rows with ID1 and ID2, and for each row either ID1 or ID2 is in the table but not both.

The IDs are all unique.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print('Generating table and matchTable...')

N = 10000
# General unique IDs list to draw from
ids = np.random.choice(a=list(range(N*100)), replace=False, size=N*10)

# First N ids go into MAIN_IDS
mainIDs = ids[:N]
data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=25, size=N)

table = pd.DataFrame({'MAIN_IDS': mainIDs, 'DATA':data})

# These ids exist in the table as MAIN_IDS
tableIdsList = np.random.choice(mainIDs, replace=False, size=int(N/10))
notInTableIdsList = ids[N:N+int(N/10)]

idsA = np.zeros(shape=(int(N/10)), dtype=np.int)
idsB = np.zeros(shape=(int(N/10)), dtype=np.int)
for i in range(len(idsA)):
    if np.random.random()>0.4:
        idsA[i] = tableIdsList[i]
        idsB[i] = notInTableIdsList[i]
    else:
        idsA[i] = notInTableIdsList[i]
        idsB[i] = tableIdsList[i]

matchTable = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': idsA, 'ID2':idsB})
print('   Done!')

print('Generating the correct result...')
correctResult = []
for i in range(len(tableIdsList)):
    correctResult.append(data[np.where(mainIDs==tableIdsList[i])[0][0]])
correctResult = np.array(correctResult)
print('   Done!')
```

I want to get DATA, where MAIN_ID==ID1 or ID2, but in the order of the matchTable.

Comment: you have two columns in match table , which one should come first ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, only one of the two column values (either ID1 or ID2) is present in the table (as MAIN_IDS). And which one is present varies by the row.

Comment: for example , id1 = [1,2] id2 =[3,4], so you want [1,2,3,4] filter out ?

Comment: it looks like: `for each row either ID1 or ID2 is in the table but not both` would play a role.

Comment: @Wen-Ben I see what you mean, no it has to be in the order of the rows. So if id1=[1,2] and id2 =[3,4] but [1,4] are present in the MAIN_IDS, then [1,4] is the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter your match table by the Id from table , then we using `reindex`

```
idx=matchTable.where(matchTable.isin(table.MAIN_IDS.tolist())).stack()

table=table.set_index('MAIN_IDS').reindex(idx).reset_index()
```

Comment: When I do matchTable.ID1.isin(table.MAIN_IDS).head(5) the IDs are found, but when I do matchTable.isin(table.MAIN_IDS).head(5) its all False.

Comment: @user1581390 matchTable.isin(table.MAIN_IDS.tolist()).